# Transfer package from vendor directly to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a package for Laravel but I want to modify one file in the package. Since the /vendor folder is in .gitignore modifications will not apply to the repo.

How can I move the package or the exact file I want to edit outside the vendor folder?

Comment: If you can, create your own file that extends this file. If you can't do that (for various reasons, the file is not a class, can't be extended, etc.), you can "fork" the repo for the package, modify the file and use your own version in `composer.json` instead of the original one. To my knowledge and experience, there isn't a way to isolate a single file from a `vendor` folder and "pull it into your project directly", but maybe someone else knows a way.

Comment: You should try to find another solution instead of editing something inside the vendor folder because is a bad practice to do that. You may loose your changes when an update on the plugin is released.

Comment: Yes. Thats why I am searching for other solutions.